# Compiling x64 with Rust on Windows

Tags: windows, rust, 64-bit

I am trying to compile x64 on Windows with Rust.

I have set: `rustup default stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc`

With the following program

```
fn main() { println!("{}", std::usize::MAX); }
```

`cargo run` prints out `4294967295`

but `cargo run --target --target x86_64-pc-windows-msvc` gives me:

```
error[E0463]: can't find crate for 'std'
  |
  = note: the 'x86_64-pc-windows-msvc' target may not be installed
```

Also `x86_64-pc-windows-msvc` is in `rustc --print target-list`

I have no idea what to do...

Answer (score 4):

This was fixed by uninstalling a rust nightly build found using `rustc --print sysroot` and reinstalling latest stable build.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is in the `note` section of the error message:

```
   = note: the 'x86_64-pc-windows-msvc' target may not be installed
```

To f